# Ubuntu 23.04 fresh install DNS not working on LAN but works perfectly on WLAN

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, dns, lan

As in the title, I am experimenting a strange behaviour on ubuntu (both 23.04 and 22 lts). DNS doesn't resolve domain addresses if connected by wired LAN,but it does it on wifi (on the same network).
I already tried resolvectl status command and it outputs the same correct values for both interfaces.
Both interfaces work quite well with numerical ip addresses.
I already tried common proposed solutions as to recreate resolv.conf simlink, but it didn't work.
I do really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Are you using an off the shelf router or some kind of heavy duty firewall on your network?  Sometimes the rules for LANs can be more strict than wifi so you might not be able to DNS query properly if the network has a firewall with heavier rules.

Comment: Nope, normal router, no firewall. Moreover the very same machine works perfectly with other OS or distros (i.e.: debian 10, Puppy linux, Raspbian, and older versions of Ubuntu, Xubuntu, etc...)